# Find the time taken by the $3$ pipes individually to fill the pool(hours) given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A swimming pool is fitted with $3$ pipes of uniform rate of flow.The first $2$ pipes operating simultaneously can fill the pool in half the time that the third pipe alone takes to fill the tank.The second pipe,to fill the pool,takes $12$ hrs more than the first pipe working alone and $8$ hrs more than the third pipe working alone.Find the time taken by the $3$ pipes individually to fill the pool(hours).

options:

a) $12$,$16$,$18$ b) $16$,$28$,$20$ c)$12$,$24$,$16$  d) $8$,$20$,$12$

MyApproach:

@Edit
Let $A$,$B$,$C$ are the pipes in the swimming pool

$1$/$A$+$1$/$B$=$2$/ $C$  ...... $1$ eqn

$1$/$B$=$1$/$12$ + $1$/$A$        .......$2$ eqn

$1$/$B$=$8$ +  $1$/$C$        ...... $3$ eqn

I have also put the  $2$ equation and $3$ equation into $1$ equation but I am getting nowhere to the Answers.

> Is my approach right?Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, b, c$ be the flow rates of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd pipes respectively.
Let $t_i$ be the time taken for the $i$-th pipe to fill.
Let $t_1=T$.
From information given, $t_2=T+12, t_3=T+4$.

Volume of tank is given by flow rate $\times$ time taken, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
at_1=bt_2=ct_3&=(a+b)\frac {t_3}2\\
aT=b(T+12)=c(T+4)&=\frac {a+b}2(T+4)\\
a+b&=2c\\
a+\frac{T}{T+12}a&=2\frac{T}{T+4}a\\
\frac{T+6}{T+12}&=\frac T{T+4}\\
(T+4)(T+6)&=T(T+12)\\
t_1=T&=12\qquad\blacksquare\\
t_2=T+12&=24\qquad\blacksquare\\
t_3=T+4&=16\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: t3=T+4 right? It is given t3=T+8?

Comment: $t_2=t_3+8$. But $t_2=t_1+12=T+12$. This gives $t_3=T+4$.

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation (a) must be wrong.  Now the third equation must be $1/A+1/B=2/C$, so answer (c) is the right one.

Comment: Is the Edit right ? On Solving I didn't get c as the Ans.

Comment: Well, $1/12+1/24=1/8=2/16$.